# Using IBPP in Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, firebird2.5

I'm working on an iPhone application. The app has to connect to Firebird. I'm trying to achieve this by using IBPP.

My problem is when I try to build and run my project in Xcode I get Apple Mach-O Linker Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_isc_array_get_slice", referenced from:
      ibpp_internals::GDS::Call() in _ibpp.o
  "_isc_array_lookup_bounds", referenced from:
      ibpp_internals::GDS::Call() in _ibpp.o
  "_isc_array_put_slice", referenced from:
      ibpp_internals::GDS::Call() in _ibpp.o
  "_isc_attach_database", referenced from:
      ibpp_internals::GDS::Call() in _ibpp.o
  "_isc_blob_info", referenced from:
      ibpp_internals::GDS::Call() in _ibpp.o
.
.
.
```

It looks like I have a similar problem:
http://sourceforge.net/p/ibpp/bugs/28/

But the answer doesn't say much for me:

> Sorry its Ok I forgot to link the -lfbclient

I assume that I need to link Firebird client library or add a Framework or something else, but when I try to add Firebird framework I also get Linker Error:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/.../Firebird.framework/Firebird' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could someone explain me step by step what should I do to force IBPP to work with objective-c in Xcode on Mac OS X?

Comment: Are you sure that it even supports iOS?

Comment: Objective c and c++ can work together, so I think this solution is supposed to work.

Comment: It's not a matter of language, it's one of operating systems. Have you tried building the library for iOS? It's not obvious from their website that it's supported - they list "Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, FreeBSD".

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to make sure you have downloaded and installed
  firebird on the machine you are developing on. [Firebird Download OSX
  Section](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/#MacOSX)
- Then, after you install this, you have to go to your project and add
  a new Framework ( *Project > Targets > Linked Frameworks and Libraries* ).
- You have to "**Add Other**" > */Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework*

This linker error should be fixed.